# How to update database table schemas with NHibernate schema generation?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, schema

I'm trying to figure out how to use NHibernate configuration with mapping to update table schemas, rather than dropping and recreating them.

Currently I'm using the `NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` obj with FluentNHibernate to generate the database schema for a mysql database.  While I can't say it's a huge problem, whenever I call `SchemaExport.Execute` on the database, it's going to drop all the tables and then recreate them.

What would be way cooler is if I could just have it update the existing table structures retaining data where possible.  But I don't really want to use a commerical product, or a code generator, because I don't like code generation in general, and I don't need this enough that I would consider paying for it. So hopefully any answer would keep these caveats in mind.

Comment: Check out [SchemaUpdate](http://morten.lyhr.dk/2008/03/nhibernates-schemaupdate-feature.html).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The **SchemaUpdate** object provides database schema updating, by apparently generating and executing a series of **SQL UPDATE** statements (as well as constraint statements) when it's `void Execute(bool script, bool doUpdate)`
 function is called.  The SchemaUpdate class is in the `NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl` namespace, which can be found in the Nhibernate.dll file.

SchemaUpdate is mentioned in chapter 15 of the nhibernate 1.0.2 toolset guide, [here](http://users.telenet.be/christianr/a_nodig_samen/VBNet/NHibernate%20Reference.pdf) (section 15.1.5).

"The NHibernate FAQ" had (link now expired) a more complete example of how to use SchemaUpdate:

```
[Test]
public void Update_an_existing_database_schema()
{
    _cfg = new Configuration();
    _cfg.Configure();
    _cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.LoadFrom("DataLayer.dll"));
    var update = new SchemaUpdate(_cfg);
    update.Execute(true, false);
}
```

Comment: we can't modify the setting of field once created for instance modify string length from nvarchar(255) to nvarchar(45), can we?

Comment: That's a good question, the create version of hbm2ddl would allows you to do this, but I've noticed sometimes I have to drop the tables before the create will run successfully.

Comment: This works brilliantly, this technique is also suited for Fluent NHibernate.

Comment: I can confirm that at least on SQL Server (and therefore on Azure), the fields are not updated, you have to manually do it.

Comment: @Astaar: do you mean that changing from nvarchar(255) to nvarchar(45) doesn't work? or do you mean that schema update doesn't work at all?