# How is hibernate_unique_key table created in a new database?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I'm trying to create my first test application with NHibernate following example in [NHibernate 2.0 Beginners Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198902). The example is using HiLo POID generator in mappings. I understand that this algorithm requires special database table to store current Hi value. But I don't understand how is this table created? Do I need to create table manually (I haven't found SQL script for this table) or should it be crated automatically by the session?

My current code is throwing exception with message: Invalid object name 'hibernate_unique_key' and table doesn't exist in my database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest a hilo per table strategy, to do this you will need to create the table `manually` and then add some rows of data e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE hibernate_unique_key (
  TableName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  NextHi bigint NOT NULL
)
```

then add a row into the database for `every` table you wish to use the hilo for: e.g.

```
CmsLogin,10
Address, 10
```

Your mappings would then contain the following:-

```
    <id name="Id" column="Id" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="hilo">
            <param name="column">NextHi</param>
            <param name="where">TableName='CmsLogin'</param>
            <param name="max_lo">100</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

and viola!

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly the part which the book is missing.

Comment: No problems, glad to be of help.

Comment: I have followed your advice but still have the same result: next_hi value is the same for all tables in each row.

Comment: To use this approach with FluentNHibernate, see this good introduction post: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2010/10/using-hilo-with-fluentnhibernate/

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest option how to generate database schema is to use the tool [hbm2ddl](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/23/nhibernate-hbm2ddl.aspx): it is just the matter of configuring session factory:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Another option which I found recently is running shema export from the code. Here are details in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366176/how-to-update-database-table-schemas-with-nhibernate-schema-generation).

Comment: I don't need to generate the whole database. I already have the empty database and I want to use HiLo POID generator.