# NHibernate xml inheritance subclass could not find column

Tags: sql-server, xml, nhibernate, subclass, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working with NHibernate for the first time. I have a table per class hierarchy (abstract super class). When I try to save a subclass (student) I get the error message:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Firstname' etc...]
```

My HBM file:

```
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="xx"
                   namespace="xx.Models">
  <class name="User" table="[User]" lazy="false">
    <id name="UserID" column="UserID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="Type" type="String"/>

    <property name="Email" column="Email" />

    <subclass name="Student" discriminator-value="0">
      <property name="Firstname" column="Firstname" />
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="Company" discriminator-value="1">
      <property name="Name" column="Name" />
    </subclass>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
UserID                  INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
Type                    CHAR(1)         NOT NULL,
Email                   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(UserID)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
UserID                  INT             NOT NULL,
Firstname               VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(UserID),
FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES [User](UserID)               
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company] (
UserID                  INT             NOT NULL,
Name                    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(UserID),
FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES [User](UserID),
);
```

I am probably missing a configuration setting, the database is MS SQL, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE (related to updated question)

In a nutshell, we need mapping `<joined-subclass>` instead of `<discriminator>`

The point is, that we use mapping for [*8.1.1. Table per class hierarchy*](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperclass) while we need

#### [8.1.2. Table per subclass](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass)

*(few cites)*

> A table-per-subclass mapping would look like:

```
<class name="IPayment" table="PAYMENT">
    <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="PAYMENT_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
    ...
    <joined-subclass name="CreditCardPayment" table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
        <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
        ...
    </joined-subclass>
    <joined-subclass name="CashPayment" table="CASH_PAYMENT">
        <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
        ...
    </joined-subclass>
    <joined-subclass name="ChequePayment" table="CHEQUE_PAYMENT">
        <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
        ...
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

> Four tables are required. The three subclass tables have primary key associations to the superclass table *(so the relational model is actually a one-to-one association).*

Similar to this we need mapping like this:

```
<class name="User" table="[User]" lazy="false">
    <id name="UserID" column="UserID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <joined-subclass name="Sutdent" table="Student">
       <key column="UserID"/>
       <property name="Firstname" column="Firstname" />
       ...
    </joined-subclass>

</class>
```

ORIGINAL part (related to original question)

In this case, the error should be really clear: There is missing column **`'Firstname'`**. Because with the  *table per class hierarchy* we simply must have all columns in our table. It is ONE table per complete hierarchy. No other place/table where to persist data...

[8.1.1. Table per class hierarchy](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperclass)

> Exactly one table is required. There is one big limitation of this mapping strategy: columns declared by the subclasses may not have NOT NULL constraints.

And in case, that you are asking: *How can NHibernate update DB schema for me?* please check this:

#### [How to update database table schemas with NHibernate schema generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/366176/1679310)

*(small extract, see the above link for all details)*

```
Configuration cfg ...
cfg.Configure();
...
var update = new SchemaUpdate(cfg);
update.Execute(true, false);
```

Comment: Hello, I'm using a table per CLASS hierarchie. I'll update my post with my create table code.

Comment: I would expect that this kind of mapping should solve your issue? Or still not on the right track?

Comment: That so great to see Dominic. Enjoy mighty NHibernate.. amazing tool ;)