# How to update the database schema using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have made some classes and their mapping classes using NHibernate and done configuration. Is it possible to update the database schema accordingly without make any  manual update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I think it's safer to create scripts to do this than to rely on nhibernate to do it for you but some updates may be possible.  See the below:

[How to update database table schemas with NHibernate schema generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366176/how-to-update-database-table-schemas-with-nhibernate-schema-generation)

Comment: @SufyanAhmad you should accept the answer if this is what you were looking for.